# Pandas: How to stack some 2D arrays on a new axis

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, python-3.6

The goal is to stack some 2D pandas dataframes along a new axis at the given level (1st, 2nd, or 3rd). I've searched but can't find a solution.

I know how to do it with numpy arrays:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2],
                [3, 4]])

stacked = np.stack((arr, arr), axis=-1)
```

makes the correct `stacked` array (the new axis is the 3rd),

```
[[[1 1]
  [2 2]]

 [[3 3]
  [4 4]]]
```

With, say, a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],
                   [3, 4]],
                  columns=['c1', 'c2'],
                  index=['i1', 'i2'])
```

what would be the equivalent operation?

Comment: ... `df.stack()` ?

Comment: pandas' `stack` doesn't work exactly the same as numpy's. I'd love to figure out how to use pandas' `stack` to do the same thing, but I don't completely understand how it works. Is it the way to go anyway?

Comment: Can you show us your desired dataframe output? Your NumPy array has an extra dimension, while Pandas will always be 2d (maybe with some MultiIndex).

Comment: @JayCalamari `stack`is pretty straightfoward. You have two rows/two columns. After stack, you'll have 4 rows, 1 column (i.e. values are pilled up)

Comment: @jcc, I've looked at it again; to be honest, I'm not sure I can do what I need to do in pandas at all. I was hoping to have a 3d array to pass to a tensorflow input that takes a 3d array as input. Can pandas do this, or do I need to convert to numpy arrays first?

Comment: @RafaelC, thanks. It doesn't actually look too bad. I'm not sure how to apply it to do what numpy's stack does, however (partially since I'm not sure if pandas dataframes can even hold the same structure and be used in the same way as 3d numpy arrays).

Comment: if you want the same output than `stacked` from the `df`, you can do `pd.concat([df.stack()]*2,axis=1).values.reshape((2, 2, 2))`, but: 1- not sure it's really efficient, 2- it's an operation on a numpy array to get 3d array anyway

Comment: @Ben.T, that's nearly it! With the limitations I think I'm finding out pandas has, it might be the best closest thing. (The one other thing I'd like to do is be able to stack on the 2nd level also. A transpose/pivot might fix that.) Thanks very much anyway.